# Meaningful Plots with Cartesian Coordinates and Geographical Coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, satellite

I am planning on using MATLAB for my desired output but I dont mind using anyother program or programming language to achieve my purpose.

I have almost 200 readings for satellite receiver location. I have x,y,x and longitude/latitude values and I want to represent the data in a meaningful plots. I want recommendations such that I can represent it in a good way. 
I have already made a 3D x,y,x plot for the readings and have also made 2D longitude and Latitude plots. Any other plots I can make from this data which can be meaningful.

Thanks

I have the following plots:

[image: First Plot]

[image: Second Plot]

[image: Third Plot]

Comment: Maybe take a look at [`compass`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compass.html) as well.  If you already have a 3D plot and 2D long/lat plots, those are good enough already.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you already have, and point out how you want them more meaningful? As @rayryeng mentioned, 3D & 2D plots are pretty good.

Comment: @Yvon I have edited my doc and have placed the plots.

Comment: Do not Understand the downvote from whoever it is. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Billa - I didn't downvote you, but I notice that people downvote for the most ridiculous reasons.  One thing you have to do (I'm still trying to do this as well) is to ignore the downvoters and focus on your question being answered.  In the end, as long as you can convey what you want properly and it gets solved, who cares for artificial points that won't benefit you in the real world?  It's the solution to your problem that matters!  BTW, thanks for updating your post with the plots.  To me you have enough plots to already describe what you want to convey.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks a lot. I will try to ignore the downvoters. Atleast I deserve a reason from downvoters so that I can improve on it.

Comment: @Billa - Agreed. I got downvoted twice on an answer that was accepted by the question poser, him telling me that it is *exactly* what he wanted. Like you, I asked for clarification and was met with silence. Sometimes downvoters downvote because they don't like how you answered the question or don't like the question itself, but lose sight of the fact that we are here to help answer questions that will benefit the asker, not questions that conform to their mile-high standards. In the end, it's what the question poser wants. I'll admit that clarity is key, but I totally understood your question.

Comment: 2 possible ideas - 1) put the dots on a 2D real-world map that shows places of interests; 2) on a 2D plot, cast different regions with some color of different opacity, according to the density of receivers (redder means more receivers).

Comment: to the frequency vs eucl. distance plot, will it be more readable if you add an illustration to show where you have put the measuring center? using a 2-D map, you can also draw some concentric circles (while their edges can be blurred to show some uncertainties) to confine an area in which most receivers are located.

Comment: @Yvon your first idea seems brilliant. Thanks

Comment: to the 3D scatter plot, personally I don't think it's meaningful to show the x-z and y-z plane. you can focus on the height of receivers, rather than view the points in two different angles (towards y-z plane and towards x-z). imagine a landscape picture in whch there are both the earth (elevation 0m) and the sky (elev 10000m). And you put the receivers in the middle to form a scatter image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively easy to plot your data in GoogleEarth.  Or rather, to create a KML (Keyhole Markup Language) file in Matlab and display the file within Google Earth.  You can find information on [Widipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) or from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/).